# Whenever I access Stack Exchange the tab appears busy

Tags: bug

I use Firefox 35.0 on my Macbook to access Stack Exchange.
Recently whenever I access a message or Community site, the "spinning circle" indicating activity starts, and never stops.
This doesn't seem to happen on other non-Stack Exchange sites.

Has there been any change to the SE code which may have caused this.

---

The Web Developer Console shows

```
The connection to ws://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/ was interrupted while the page was loading. full.en.js:1
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: I think I am seeing the same thing and have let @stackstatus know via Twitter.  It seems to be related to imgur.com because when it eventually stops spinning the images do not appear but some icon placeholders do.  I'm in Brisbane and I see you are in Sydney so it seems that only Australian users are affected.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem in Internet Explorer, Chrome and Firefox as well as from the iPhone App and when I perform Windows Network Diagnostics on http://i.stack.imgur.com they report that "website (http://i.stack.imgur.com) is online but isn't responding to connection attempts".

Comment: (Not sure off-hand what's going on here, but retagging so it pops up on our radar later.)

Comment: I am seeing this in Chrome - and images often do not show

Comment: What does you Network tab showing?

Comment: @ShadowWizard in the Developer Tools, the error states `http://i.stack.imgur.com/p1EAI.jpg?s=24&g=1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: So something on your end is blocking/slowing down imgur.com domain - maybe firewall, router settings, ISP block etc.

Comment: @SabreTooth This is a different problem - you should post your own issue

Comment: Interesting, it is pretty much the same as what PolyGeo is stating, I get the  busy spinning circle and it started suddenly yesterday.

Comment: @SabreTooth Possibly, it may even be ultimately caused by the same issue, but my pages apperr to load perfectly, and do not access imgur.com, which is just obscuring the issue.

Comment: @ShadowWizard please see my answer below

Comment: @Milliways pages without images are loading fine for me - please see my answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo I am also Australian (Capicornia Coast) and experiencing the same

Comment: @SabreTooth I'm hoping it will resolve overnight - I plan to retest tomorrow morning

Comment: huh, guess it's contagious. Just started happening for me too, on all pages. @Anna did you change something in the host/network/routers/etc?

Comment: @Anna also, in tracert I get 9 different lines for atlas.cogentco.com, is this normal?

Comment: Happens to me as well.

Comment: You may want to campare notes with [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251064/possble-imgur-block-by-german-isp-1und1). One German provider is affected, two others are not, or maybe not fully..??

Comment: @ShadowWizard it seems to be more widespread - which is not so good, but fixable (potentially), but it means I am not going crazy in this respect.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just did a tracert and got 8 lines for cogent as well

Comment: @Sab yeah, let's hope Anna can shed some light over this. :)

Comment: Maybe of help - but a tracert to i.stack.imgur.com went through fine from here in central Queensland.

Answer (score 7):

We have reached out to imgur about this (who was unaware of any current issues). They are getting with CloudFlare which i.stack.imgur.com cached through to track down the issue.

We are aware of the issue, just was waiting to post until I had actual confirmation a problem was reproduced. I'll update this as soon as I hear more from them.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for chasing this up for us!

Comment: It appears to be fixed at my workplace - I would imagine this will be the case when I get home too.

Comment: It's fixed for me too  - thanks!  CC @SabreTooth

Comment: Yup, confirmed - all good here at home as well - thank you to the SE Team for getting this sorted

Answer (score 2):

I have been experiencing the same thing as PolyGeo using Chrome - I have changed my avatar to the default identicon and that stopped the busy spinning thing on my profile page, however, half of the images in chat rooms are not showing and the busy spinning signal still occurs.

However, images in most questions and answers are not showing with the busy spinning signal.  The error I have seen in the Chrome Developer Tools is a timeout for the imgur files, an example is below:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1EAI.jpg?s=24&g=1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

I also tested this on my work and home computers which are on different systems.  I can access the imgur.com website.

One more thing I have noticed - the same thing occurs on my phone browser (not the app, but viewing the sites using the browser).

Another edit to include further information:

- Milliways, PolyGeo and I live in Australia
- a tracert from home to i.stack.imgur.com went through without time outs or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use this "answer" to describe my symptoms in more detail - they may or may not be related!

Today when I visit [Creating one dataset from several overlapping point datasets using ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138320/creating-one-dataset-from-several-overlapping-point-datasets-using-modelbuilder) (or any Q&A with images) the page goes into a spin and a couple of minutes later it does finish loading but only has an icon where the picture should be.
Note: I cannot actually see the image below because of this so I am hoping that it shows up to those who need to see it.

[image]

The browser console reports:

> GET https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GlqX.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I see this in Chrome and Internet Explorer, and on my iPhone using the app I do not see images either.

Something else which may or may not be relevant is that when I look at the Users for any SE site the pictures only show up for about half of the users while the page goes into a spin.

Comment: I am finding the exactly same thing with Chrome and have tried at work and at home.