# Possble imgur block by German ISP 1und1

Tags: discussion, imgur, blocked

Since yesterday, March 10, 2015 I find that anything from i.stack.imgur.com won't load anymore (unless I still have it cached..), loading never finishes, images are not displayed..

Question: does anybody else see this?

My provider is 1und1 in Germany; I have contacted them, but would like to hear from other customers, if they experience the same issue?

I tried several browsers on several machines, all with the same result; and also on other folks machines with different IPSs, all of which work fine..

The issue is both with any StackExchange site (with images on  imgur) and also with loading images from there directly, e.g.:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4y77.png
```

**Update** Seems like the problem has been fixed by today (March 12 '15).
No explanation yet; I suspect it got onto a Blacklist..

Comment: You're not the only one, and it's not specific to a single ISP. Something is off, maybe on imgur side.

Comment: Good to hear from you. Not sure, both IPSs #KabelDeutschland' and 'mNet' don't have this issue!

Comment: I see this happening on and off today, and use a totally different ISP, hence my conclusion.

Comment: @TaW: Are you sure? I thought I'm routed through mNet, but no images show for me either.

Comment: Well wrt mNet, I have to rely on my daughter's word, but she could read me the text in the image above..